# Getting heads ten times in a row with 2 tries per attempt

Tags: probability

If someone was to attempt to flip get 10 heads with two attempts per try (for example he'd flip a coin and it'd come up tails then he'd flip it again and it'd come up heads and then he repeats this 10 times) would the probability of success be 1 in 3/4^10?

Comment: Yes, but you have to write $(3/4)^{10}$ and it is not $1$ in ..., but simply $(3/4)^{10}=0.0563\cdots$

Comment: Saying "1 in (3/4)^10" makes no sense (although saying "approximately 1 in 18" would make sense).

Comment: The probabability IS $(3/4)^{10} $ or $0.0563135147$